# MVC read label value and pass to controller on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller

I have an MVC razor view with partial views on it. Upon button click in the main view I have to trigger a controller action. I need to pass a `label` value to this action. So I thought I could just get the label value using jQuery after all the HTML is populated. This `label` is in a partial view and my script is in the main view. I keep getting an empty value in alerts, even after the page is fully loaded. Here is the code I have used:

```html
<input type="button" class="ViewInfo-success" value="View History" onclick="return HistoryResponse()" />
```

```js
function HistoryResponse() {
    var mac = $('#cmmac').html();
    alert("alert1" + mac);

    try {
        location.replace('/HistoryLookup/GetHistory' + mac);
    }
});
```

Label code in the partial view:

```html
<div class="col-lg-2">
   @Html.Label("MAC Seria:", new { id = "cmmac" })
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2">
   @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.HistoryDO.MACSerial)
</div>
```

Is there any other way to achieve this? Please input any ideas.

Comment: What is the `#cmmac` element?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I assume it is the id of the element `@Html.Label("MAC Seria:", new { id = "cmmac"})`

Comment: Yep, makes sense now after the edit. @OP given the code your URL would be this: `'/HistoryLookup/GetHistoryMAC Seria:` which seems wrong. What is the actual URL you're trying to build?

Comment: the url i am trying to access is /HistoryLookup/GetHistory    I would like to pass the value of that cmmac label to my action which is 'GetHistory' in the HistoryLookup controller.                                                                       Also that label value is populated using the model which is referred on main view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

**Before Click (Edit):**

[image: BeforeClick]

**On Click (Edit):**

[image: OnClick]

**Post Click Url (Edit):**

[image: PostClick]

**View (Index):**

```
<input type="button" class="ViewInfo-success" value="View History" onclick="HistoryResponse()" />

@Html.Partial("MACSerialPartial")

<script>
    function HistoryResponse() {
        var mac = document.getElementById('cmmac').innerText;
        alert("alert1" + mac);
        location.replace('/HistoryLookup/GetHistory?id=' + mac);
    };
</script>
```

**Partial View with Edit (MACSerialPartial):**

```
@model mvc_read_label_value.Models.Product

<div class="col-lg-2">
    <p>MAC Serial:</p>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-2">
    <p id="cmmac">@Model.HistoryDO.MACSerial</p>
</div>
```

**Model:**

```
public class Product
{
    public History HistoryDO { get; set; }
}

public class History
{
    public string MACSerial { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller with Index Action Method:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Product product = new Product() {HistoryDO = new History(){MACSerial = "TestSerial"} };
        return View(product);
    }
}
```

**HistoryLookup Controller:**

```
public class HistoryLookupController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetHistory(string id)
    {
        return View(); // TODO: need to make a view corresponding to this action
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Bwyn,Thanq for your elaborate response. I need that macid value 'testserial' be passed to controller. I get alert eith empty cMMac Serial: too But I need the value of that label 'testserial' how do i capture that?

Answer (score 0):

So all i had to do is store the macid value from model in a hidden field like this.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Model.historyDO.MACSerial, new { id = "macId", name = "macId" })
```

Button on Main view

```
<input type="button" class="ViewInfo btn btn-success" value="View History" onclick="return HistoryResponse()" />
```

In the historyresponse() method get the value by hidden field id

```
function HistoryResponse() {
        var params = '?MacId=' + $("#macId").val();
        alert("alert3" + params); [![enter image description here][1]][1]
        try {
            location.replace('/HistoryLookup/GetHistory' + params);
        }
        catch (exception) { }
    }
```

And post to action.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetHistory(string macId)
{    
var model = Repository.GetHistory(macId);
return View("HistoryLookupResponse", model);

}
```